# Join Contact data with my table in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have table with contacts identified by LOOKUP_KEY and I need JOIN it with system contact data to get real name and photo. Is possible do this? Or I must read contact data for every contact item CursorAdapter and get required information about contact?

This question is related to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222297/custom-contacts-view-join-or-combine-contactscontract-with-sqlite-table.
But it's without reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is going to be to read the data through the [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), and put it in your own database. Afterwards you can perform JOIN queries with the data.

Comment: I was afraid this answer. I hope in better solutions :-( But thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [CursorJoiner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html) would do the trick?